Simple parameterization for similar Hermitian matrices
Let $D = 2^N$ where $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider a $D \times D$ Hermitian matrix $H_0$ (i.e. $H = H^\dagger$) with eigenvalues $\Lambda := \{\lambda_i\}$. Is there a simple parameterization of the set of matrices $\mathcal{S}_{H_0}$ similar to $H_0$? Concretely, the set I want to parameterize is
$$\mathcal{S}_{H_0} := \{UH_0U^\dagger:U\in SU(D)\}.$$
A straightforward parameterization of $\mathcal{S}_{H_0}$ would be to parameterize the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(D)$ to induce a parameterization of the unitaries $U \in SU(D)$ via the exponential map. However, this parameterization is not amenable to the computations I am doing (exponentiating matrices is computationally expensive).
An ideal parameterization would be more of the form
$$H(\theta_1, \theta_2, ...):=\sum_{\theta_1,\theta_2,...}f(\theta_1,\theta_2,...)M_{\theta_1, \theta_2,...}.$$
